# Convert non-hex text in varchar(max) to varbinary

Tags: sql-server, file, binary, attachment

I have a table in SQL Server, with binary data stored as a string in a `varchar(max)` field.

The table name is attachment, and the field is named "documentbody".

```
select id, mimetype, documentbody
from attachment
```

The files stored in the table are mostly PDF, but also include JPG and PNG and probably some other file types too.

Here is a sample of what one of the "files" looks like, when queried (first 100 characters only):

> JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MNCjEgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZSAvUGFnZQovUGFyZW50IDIgMCBSCi9NZWRpYUJveCBbIDAgMCA2MTIuMDAw

How can I convert this data into actual binary data?

[image: screenshot of query results]

Comment: The end goal is to move the data into a wholly new system (Salesforce). I can do that if the data is in a binary field, or if I have access to the files in a local file directory (I already have a cursor / bcp written, but dumping the varchar data directly to a file doesn't work - file is not readable). Cursor/BCP dump to file is probably the "hard" way anyway, haha. If I can write a select query that converts the varchar into varbinary, that is probably the best way.

Comment: Wow. I think that actually did the trick! Thank you!! Post this as the answer so we can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one wishes to convert data from one datatype to another, and no implicit convert exists, one uses either [`CAST` or `CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

e.g.

```
select cast(MyColumn as varbinary(max)), convert(varbinary(max), MyColumn)
from MyTable;
```

`CAST` is ANSI-SQL for what it is worth whereas `CONVERT` is SQL Server specific. However `CONVERT` handles many other cases including specific formatting, which `CAST` doesn't handle.

---

OK, taking a total guess here, many people encode binary data as `base64` so try this:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("MyColumn"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)') AS VARCHAR(MAX))
FROM MyTable;
```

Comment: Erk... I'm sorry, I think I spoke too soon. It appears that the convert code turned the text itself into a binary representation of the text. The convert function did not produce a useable file.

Comment: @FNG do you have an example of what the conversion results *should* be? And do you know how the data was saved in the first place - i.e. what conversion/transformation took place to get from a binary file to a varchar string?

Comment: The files are supposed to be PDFs / pngs / jpgs. I have file names in the same table in the same row (column name is "filename"), with the proper expected extensions. I am trying the conversions and dumping them to files, and trying to open them to see if it worked, but so far each time I try to open a PDF it says it's an invalid format.

Comment: I understand that, but to be able to convert them back to what they were originally I need to know what that transformation is since its not just a simple convert.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. Unfortunately, I do not really know how the data was converted to varchar(max) in the first place. So, finding out what encoding it is currently is a pretty big challenge. I'm trying to eyeball it, but that's all I can really do. I suspect base64 though.

Comment: Sample (first ~400ish characters of a "pdf"): JVBERi0xLjYNCjcgMCBvYmoNCjw8IC9MZW5ndGggMjExMiAvRmlsdGVyIC9GbGF0ZURlY29kZSA+Pg0Kc3RyZWFtDQqUfyf1yvAi1BZIqsBwuJ5wIb4tmVXRfimIdavE/8aEkLyWUnOxMDO4sTa8cdosdpZGqaGgQCAiUEofSpN0uMybu3lTU7XUIKJqNhayr0m8FryE4sGQi2+mhl3k9CDVpy2F7B+104iMl+NcF7WdXF9AQebLIzNtvuq8Egt91MXvvb0X0Lw5+/MGiohxoo19+7x9FkDHZYDhKmnnVIrP1BHLCVvVq8FSk0LlUdbMCaPqPYZstPrsDu1hJIXnI2pOR/XBjY+9V75celMBh7/DzMYo5ZEtvT5k3Gu5pzdyv1pQkdoYw62SfbCu5C8BFUzQU

Comment: Hi @dale, trying it out right now! Your code does seem to bring order to the chaos, and the output looks like PDF encoding. I'm working on testing it out right now, but it looks very promising!